# System of equations in distance problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for posting such an elementary question, I got stuck on Discord and others also got stuck, could someone help me out?

Two trains were going against each other from city A and city B. When they met, it turned out that the train from B had traveled 40 kilometers less. The train from A arrived in B after 13/6 hours after the meeting, and the train from B arrived in A 24/13 after the meeting. Find their average speeds.

Here is my attempt:

Let $x,y$ denote speeds of city A and city B respectively. Then at some given time if city A traveled $d$, then we have
$$\frac{d}{x}=\frac{d-40}{y}$$

And for the remainder of their journey after they meet:

$$d-40=\frac{13}{6}x, d = \frac{24}{13}y$$

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible unless we assume that the trains travel at constant speed, which is nowhere stated.  In fact, the direction "Find their average speeds," would seem to indicate that the speeds aren't constant.  But I guess that assuming the speeds are constant, as you are doing, is the only thing possible.  Badly-phrased question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with SaulSpatz, and would like to offer the following alternative viewpoint.

Assume that the **fixed** speeds of $A,B$ are $S_A, S_B$, respectively.  Further, assume that the distance traveled by $A,B$ prior to their meeting was $D$ and $D-40$, respectively.

When they meet, they have both traveled the same amount of time.  Therefore, you have that

$$\frac{D}{S_A} = \frac{D-40}{S_B}.  \tag1$$

You also know, based on how long it took each of $A,B$ to complete their respective journeys, that

$$\frac{D - 40}{(13/6)} = S_A, ~~\frac{D}{(24/13)} = S_B. \tag2$$

Therefore,

$$S_A = \frac{6(D-40)}{13} ~~\text{and} ~~S_B = \frac{13D}{24}.\tag3$$

Using equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ together, you have that

$$\frac{(D)(13)}{(6)(D-40)} = \frac{(D-40)(24)}{(13)(D)}.$$

This implies that $$(D^2)(13)^2 = (12)^2(D-40)^2.\tag4$$

However, equation (4) above is clearly **impossible** because the two LHS factors are larger than the two RHS factors.

---

**Addendum**
In hindsight, the same conclusion may be reached merely by examining the **concepts** underlying equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ above.

When $A,B$ meet, $A$ has covered more ground.  Therefore, $S_A > S_B.$

When completing their journeys, $A$ takes slightly longer (i.e. $[13/6] > [24/13]$) to cover *less ground*.  Therefore $S_A < S_B$.

Therefore, these constraints, coupled with the assumption that the speeds of $A,B$ are each constant immediately leads to a contradiction.

---

**Addendum-1**

For what it's worth, there are two ways that I see of resolving the contradiction:

1. Assume that the original question has a typo, and that the completion times of $(13/6)$ and $(24/13)$ have been reversed.  That is, assume that $A$ takes $(24/13)$ to complete its journey and $B$ takes $(13/6)$ to complete its journey.
2. Assume that $A,B$ did not start from their respective cities simultaneously.  That is, assume that $B$ started later than $A$.

Obviously, neither assumption can be explored prior to receiving feedback from the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

This question makes no sense to me.  Let the distance between the cities be $D=2d$ and suppose the trains start at time $0$. Let $t$ be the time at which the trains meet.  At that point, train A has traveled $d+20$ miles and train B has traveled $d-20$ miles.

The average speed of train A over the whole distance is $$\frac D{t+13/6}$$ and we are given nothing that relates $D$ and $t$.  So, as I said in a comment, I can only suppose that we are to assume that the trains travel at constant speed throughout their journeys.  For train A, we have $$\frac{d+20}t=\frac{d-20}{13/6}$$ or clearing deominators
$$\frac{13}6d+\frac{260}6=dt-20t\tag1$$
For train B, we get
$$\frac{d-20}t=\frac{d+20}{24/13}$$ or
$$\frac{24}{13}d-\frac{480}{13}=dt+20t\tag2$$  Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ gives $$\left(\frac{24}{13}-\frac{13}6\right)d-\frac{480}{13}-\frac{260}6=40t\tag3$$ but this is nonsense.

We have $$\frac{24}{13}<2<\frac{13}6$$ so that each term on the left-hand side of $(3)$ is negative, leading to an impossible value for $t$.

Are you certain you have transcribed the question correctly?